# Order of loaded assets not according asset files

Tags: jquery-ui, yii2

For using the Tooltip function of bootstrap v3.4.1 with YII2.0.18 the order of the loaded javascripts must be changed. I can't fix it.

After upgrading to YII2.0.18 the order of the loaded javascripts is changed. Formerly scripts where loaded in this order:

- jquery-ui.js
- bridge.js
- bootstrap.js

Now it is as follows:

- bootstrap.js
- jquery-ui.js
- bridge.js

Due to this change the bridge.js script can't rewrite the tooltip functionname of the JqueryUI script before the bootstrap.js is loaded.

I use the following command in the bridge.js:

```
$.widget.bridge('uitooltip', $.ui.tooltip);
```

The AppAsset file:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/main.css',
        'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'css/multi-select.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/main.js',
        'js/invoiceLines.js',
        'js/rememberTabs.js',
        'js/jquery.multi-select.js'
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'app\assets\BridgeAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    ];
}
```

And the BridgeAsset file

```
class BridgeAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $js = [
        'js/bridge.js'
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\jui\JuiAsset',
    ];
}
```

I can't get changed the order of the loaded scripts unless I experimented with dependencies in the assetfiles.

Comment: `BootstrapPluginAsset` depends on `BootstrapAsset` so you don't have to add both explicitly. Same for `JuiAsset` and `JqueryAsset`. Maybe you could add your own `BootstrapAsset` that loads Bootstrap files and depends on `BridgeAsset` - this way it should be added after bridge.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer, in web.php i added the following under assetManager:

```
'bundles' => [
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                    'depends' => [
                        'yii\jui\JuiAsset',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
```

This makes the JqueryUI depending of the bootstrap assets.